# Port selection for local IPEndPoint creation. Does port number matter?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udpclient

This is the first time I'm working with IPEndPoint, so pardon my lack of experience.

If I create an IPEndPoint like this:

```
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.25"), 0);
```

Is it possible that port 0 will already be in-use such that this will produce an exception?  Is there any type of convention here for which local port number to use?  Should I just use a randomly generated number that's less than 65,536?  Is there a best or safest approach to choosing a port and does it even matter?

The use case in this particular instance is just for me to learn more.  I'm fiddling with sending UDP broadcast WOL packets at the moment, but later I expect to get into a bit more complicated code.  I just want to make sure I understand best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)

> Port numbers are assigned in various ways, based on three ranges:
>   System Ports (0-1023), User Ports (1024-49151), and the Dynamic and/or
>   Private Ports (**49152-65535**); the difference uses of these ranges is
>   described in [RFC6335]. System Ports are assigned by IETF process for
>   standards-track protocols, as per [RFC6335].  User Ports are assigned
>   by IANA using the "IETF Review" process, the "IESG  Approval" process,
>   or the "Expert Review" process, as per [RFC6335].  Dynamic Ports are
>   not assigned.

Also from the UdpClient(port) ctor MSDN documentation:

> If you pass 0 to the constructor, the underlying service provider will assign a port number.

Comment: I understand the IANA documentation.  What I don't understand is exactly when it really matters and when it doesn't.  What I mean to say is that suppose I choose port 49153, but Joe Coder also wrote something using 49153.  If I need to bind to a local endpoint for a moment to send a UDP packet, will I get an exception if Joe Coder's app is already running?  If my app needs only to send UDP packets now and then, would I be better off choosing a randomly generated port number between 49152 and 65535 so that I can retry on failure with a new port number rather than sticking with a static 49153?

Comment: If you are just sending then don't use the UdpClient actor that takes an IPEndPoint.  That one is only useful for receiving.  Just use the parameterless actor or the one that takes an AddressFamily.

Comment: The IP stack will manage your local port if all you are doing is sending.

Comment: I was doing that initially, but then I discovered that when sending WOL packets to 255.255.255.255 you have to individually bind to each adapter and send the packet to make sure you get your packet sent on the correct network.  The automatic selection that is done for you when you don't specify an IPEndPoint is not sufficient in this case since it might send to a network that you don't care about.

Comment: DOH! I see now that the MSDN documentation for the IPEndPoint constructor also states that you can use 0 to specify any available port!  Not sure how I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, right you are.  Well I don't know the correct answer in this case.  But in the time it takes someone to post the correct answer you could just fire up 2 or more copies of your program and find the answer yourself.

Comment: @dizzy.stackoverflow Sorry guys, stepped away from my machine for a minute.  Great discussion and answer. +1

Comment: @paqogomez - no worries at all.  Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

First, you would want to check to see if you are interfering with any [standard windows service ports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959833.aspx)

Random in that case would be a very bad way to go, the port may be in use by some other app.

But you can always [go here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) and choose something that is unassigned.

There, the IANA says

> The Dynamic and/or Private Ports are those from 49152 through 65535

Comment: I understand the IANA documentation.  What I don't understand is exactly when it really matters and when it doesn't.  What I mean to say is that suppose I choose port 49153, but Joe Coder also wrote something using 49153.  If I need to bind to a local endpoint for a moment to send a UDP packet, will I get an exception if Joe Coder's app is already running?  If my app needs only to send UDP packets now and then, would I be better off choosing a randomly generated port number between 49152 and 65535 so that I can retry on failure with a new port number rather than sticking with a static 49153?